# Getting null while reading image through URL using Angular JS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have an URL, for eg: w3schools image. When I try to read image and calculate its width and height, I'm getting null at `img.src=imgData`.
This is the code I'm trying.Why I'm not able to read image from this URL.

```
var imgData = https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_fjords.jpg;
img.src = imgData;
img.onload = function () {
  $rootScope.width = this.width;
  $rootScope.height = this.height;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get image size (height & width) using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/623172/how-to-get-image-size-height-width-using-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

You can try clientwidth and clientheight as well .

```
var imgData = https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_fjords.jpg;
    img.src = imgData;
    img.onload = function () {
       $rootScope.width = this.clientWidth;;
       $rootScope.height = this.clientHeight;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `naturalHeight` and `naturalWidth` on the image element. Like this:

```
var imgData = https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_fjords.jpg;
img.src = imgData;
img.onload = function () {
   $rootScope.width = this.naturalWidth;
   $rootScope.height = this.naturalHeight;
}
```